# What are the criterias in selecting language groovy vs Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, groovy

What are the parameters considered in selecting groovy on grails framework or plain spring MVC based java application.

Considering a deals site www.deals2buy.com site which has 
-rich content(images only) on the website
-reports for the admin
-normal CRUD operations
-heavy traffic on last days of the deals
Which language/technology would you choose for this kind of application?

Thanks in advance.
enthusiasts

Answer (score 1):

My 2ct: if you need each single bit of performance I'd say go straight for Java. But of course given the fact that you can mix and match both, call one from another, you could work in Groovy and call Java for all that needs performance.

Groovy/Grails will give you faster turnaround, scaffolding, gorm, much less code and generally a lot of syntax sugar. And less speed.
Java has speed, and if comparing Java on one of the wide range of available containers to put your web app in, very good and mature management tools (which is good for production!).

But again since Groovy runs on JVM you should be able to develop in Groovy and deploy the app in a Java container and have your management tools (in this scenario Groovy != Grails).

So it will turn down to: how important it is to have good management tools? do you need all the speed you can get? which syntax do you feel more comfortable with? how much development productivity will the generators/gorm buy you (there is nothing you couldn't do in Java)? how do you plan to make your views: JSP, JSF, any other templating framework or prefer groovy templates?

Comment: Thanks TS for your inputs. 
(Groovy!= Grails)
So you mean to say- app based on Groovy can be managed by tools but not Grails. But we do deploy grails app on tomcat, so isn't't the same thing?

Comment: Groovy != Grails means you could write code in Groovy and deploy it as part of Java webapp in Tomcat, JBoss or whatever without Grails - because of interoperability between Groovy and Java. In other words: Groovy = language, Grails = language plus web app framework plus scaffolding plus gorm. You can take all or just take the language and still be more productive because of much more concise syntax. And if you can deploy grails apps in Tomcat and use its management, well, that's pretty cool.

Comment: So I'm afraid there is no clear answer based just on the language and you have to take other arguments into account.

Comment: What I feel is very important is to have reliable and accurate management tools, you could try it out if Tomcat (if that's your container) does it well enough incl. seeing all pages, being able to define and monitor database pool connections etc.

Comment: Thanks again for the prompt response.